# how to export a child function from a parent function?

Tags: reactjs

I usually export one function as a default function or tow function but i never exported a child function like the function `isdown`. So, how to export it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/style.css'



function Boxshape({ className, Items, i }) {
    
      const [dowPostion, setpostion] = useState(false)
      function isdown() {
            return dowPostion
      }

      return (
            
                        <div
                              onMouseDown={() => setisDown(true)}
                              onMouseUp={() => setisDown(false)}
                        >testing </div>
      )
}

export default Boxshape
export { Boxshape.isdown }
```

- note: I know `export { Boxshape.isdown }` this is wrong way, but I write it as a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you make function `isDown` a seperate function like this. if you do this you can call it anywhere you want or you can declare in parent and pass it to the child.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/style.css'

export const isdown=(dowPostion)=>{
 return dowPostion
}

function Boxshape({ className, Items, i }) {
    
      const [dowPostion, setpostion] = useState(false)
      isdown(dowPostion)

      return (
            
                        <div
                              onMouseDown={() => setpostion(true)}
                              onMouseUp={() => setpostion(false)}
                        >testing </div>
      )
}

export default Boxshape
```

Comment: their is a bug with this way... when I export `isdown` return undefined even when I the mouse down... at the same time when I `consule.log(dowPostion)` inside `Boxshape` function it return true

Comment: in ur code state management is wrong if u want to make it true u need to call setPosition(true) and isDown function not needed

Comment: I need isDown function to export it and read if by other function in other files.

Comment: ok u need pass dowPosition in argument example like this console.log(isdown(dowPosition )) because the outer isDown function doesnt know dowPosition variable remember if the function not in same js file u need to import the function